# how to clear xml http (xhr) response while connection is open

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

At my servlet I am setting the following and on every second I am flushing data to the response's outputstream

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
response.addHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");

while(true){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    resOut.write(hello);
    resOut.flush();
}
```

On my client side javascript I have the ajax

```
xmlhttp.onprogress = function() {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```

The browser is receiving the flushed data and alert is firing but the problem I am facing is that the responseText is coming out too large an object instead of chunks and if I try to set reponseType to arrybuffer or blob etc, on the xmlhttp object, I am seeing null until the response stream is closed from the server as expected.

So how to clear the responseText(_read only) at the intermediate stage or be able to use arraybuffer and receive chunks to make the data available on the html page while the connection is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can know, this is how the HTTP protocol works. You won't be able to read the response (or chunks from it) until everything was finished.

You have 2 workarounds for it:

1. You either use a timeout and request a flush, so you need a pseudo-state on the server (use an operation id and a flag of the "content already flushed") - (long/short)[http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery] polling technique.
2. Or use [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/). You can write a chunk on the socket, the client receives it and does whatever it wants with it. If you have experience with sockets from other programming languages, you'll find it easy to understand. But be careful that some browsers (i'm talking about IE here) doesn't [support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets).

There may be a 3 here, but depends on the server language you are using. I'm a .NET developer and i know only about SignalR.

Comment: Thanks, going with WebSockets, every other way seems to be dead end, if you have any working model with xhr streams let me know.

Comment: You're welcome! And thanks for accepting the response. Sadly, I don't have one. On all the projects I worked on, web sockets and SignalR were more than enough :(